# Repat Column in R with different arrangement of rows each time

Tags: r, vector, rep

I have a vector in R, called v, such that `v <- c(1,3,4,5,2)`.

I am trying to create 50 repetitions of this vector, but would like to re-arrange the indices randomly and non-repeating for each repetition, i.e.,

```
reps <- c(1,3,4,5,2  1,2,3,4,5) etc...
```

I tried:

```
reps <- rep(sample(1:5, 5, replace = FALSE), 50)
```

but this just repeats the same sample 50 times.

Answer (score 1):

May be we can use

```
c(replicate(50, sample(v)))
```